# Receive SMS webhook not working in Twilio

Tags: twilio

[image]

I added webhook url for message comes in for a phone number.
but i can't receive event when  receive sms on that url.

Comment: Are you sure the webhook isn't called? It's usually best to start looking at the [Message Logs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools) to see if the incoming message shows there with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it looks like you have added this phone number to your `Default Messaging Service for Conversations`.
Most likely, you didn't mean to do this, so you can remove the phone number from the Messaging Service by clicking on the link inside "Remove this phone number from Default Conversations Service".
Then remove the phone number from the Sender Pool.

If you do want the number in the service, navigate to your Messaging Service (**Messaging > Services > your messaging service**), click on the **Integration** link.
Here you can configure how the webhook should be handled:
[image: Integration settings for Twilio Messaging Service]

If you select "Defer to sender's webhook", it'll send the webhook requests to the webhook you configured on the phone number itself.